# How do I infer an upper bound for this generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface as follows:

```
public interface ImportedEntity<T extends ImportedEntity<T, E>, E extends Enum<E>>
```

I want a class with an *upperbound* of that interface:

```
Class<ImportedEntity<?, ?>> c = ImportedEntity.class;
Class<ImportedEntity<?, ?>> c = ImportedEntitySubclass.class;
```

These obviously doesn't compile because of the **wildcard**, but in terms of what I should be putting instead of the wildcards in order to get it to compile, my head is about to explode.

Worst comes to the worst I can use raw types, but I get the feeling if I do that I will have gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an unchecked cast on the right hand side like this:

```
Class<ImportedEntity<?, ?>> c = (Class<ImportedEntity<?, ?>>) ImportedEntity.class;
Class<ImportedEntity<?, ?>> c = (Class<ImportedEntity<?, ?>>) ImportedEntitySubclass.class;
```

I am afraid that *somewhere* you will have to make the unchecked cast and live with the warning, since the `class` property cannot hold the type information.